# How to stop to load a Configuration class (@Configuration) in Spring or Spring batch?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a spring batch configuration class which will insert mongo documents on a scheduled time. But since it is a configuration class mongo documents are getting inserted once before the schedule time. I will need to ignore the insertion which is happening before the schedule time.

Please help, any suggestions would be helpful!

Comment: Maybe the parameter `spring.batch.job.enabled=false` in your properties file can help ?

Comment: Why have it in a configuration file?

Comment: GrechkaVassili, I am using @EnableBatchProcessing at class level in the same batch configuration class.

Comment: Thomas Andolf, It's a batch file and there only all the reader, writer, job etc beans are defined. It doesn't have any issues.

Comment: Grechka Vassili, working with **spring.batch.job.enabled=false**. Thanks much!